# low disk space on file system root

Tags: filesystem, root

I am working with Ubuntu 20.04. I had my ssd swapped for a larger one and had restored an image of the older one by a technician. It worked fine until recently the error "Low Disk Space on "Filesystem root" appeared. Ubuntu is then getting very slow. I have tried to clean up space by using te commands "sudo apt autoremove" and "sudo apt clean" but those didn't help.
Filesystem root is on partition 4, wich has 375 GB of wich 50 GB free space....

```
df -h gives as a response:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
tmpfs           782M   11M  771M   2% /run  
efivarfs        128K  101K   23K  82% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars  
/dev/sda4       369G  319G   32G  92% /  
tmpfs           3,9G   56M  3,8G   2% /dev/shm  
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock  
/dev/sda1       100M   32M   68M  33% /boot/efi  
tmpfs           782M  112K  782M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Root is on sda4 wich is flagged as diag

How can I change the space for filesystem root?

[image]

Comment: How much space will you need? If it’s just a little more, you could consider changing the amount of reserved disk space on `/` to something like 10GB. If you are going to regularly work with large numbers of files, another storage device will be needed 

Comment: Do you have any old kernel versions lying around? That is what gave me this problem. Use this command to find them:

`dpkg -l | awk '/linux-image/ {print $2}'`

Use apt-get purge to get rid of old ones.

Comment: How can I increase the disk space on / by 10 GB?
Root is on "/dev/sda4       369G  319G   32G  92% / " so I guess there should be suficcient space to increase space for root.
Btw, how should I insert the gray ribbon for quoting the above quote?

Comment: @jeffas apt-get purge provokes an error message:
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
What can I do?

Comment: Aside: For having code greyed, simplest way is to put it between back-ticks (unless, of course, you have backticks in the code fragment). For more info, click on the "Learn about formatting..." link below in the Help box.

Comment: apt-get purge needs to be run with sudo

Comment: I have been trying a lot of your suggestions and more suggestions that I found elsewhere as well, and almost messed up my SSD so far that it did not boot anymore. I really can't reproduce all what I tried out. Finally I succeeded to help myself with Boot-Repair that I found here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair/ and got my system booting normally again. 
I had to drop some films ( about 70 GB) to make it work and now all works fine again.
This thread can be closed now......